# Sum using XMM registers using FASM under Linux OS

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, fasm

Sum using xmm regsisters using fasm - linux:

```
$./fasm file.asm
$ gcc -s file.o -o file -lm
```

The result should be 14 , but I got `7.000000000000000000000000000000`.

This is the source code:

```
format elf64
extrn printf

section '.data' writeable align 16
rad dq 7.0
fmt db "%.30lf",0ah,0

section '.text' executable align 16
public main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    pxor xmm0,xmm0
    movsd xmm0,[rad]
    pxor xmm2,xmm2
    movsd xmm2,[rad]
    addsd xmm2,xmm0
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,fmt
    call printf

    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Replay `adds xmm2, xmm0` with `adds xmm0, xmm2` to store the result of the addition in `xmm0` instead of `xmm2` as `printf` expects.

Comment: thank's . I think I'm tired, obviously the result xmm2 will be add to  xmm0. printf has need just rax and rdi ( two args).

Comment: `movsd` loads don't have a false dependency; you don't need to `pxor xmm0,xmm0` ahead of `movsd` for performance or correctness.  It already zero-extends the 64-bit load to 128-bit.  Just `movsd xmm0, [rad]` / `addsd xmm0, xmm0` or `addsd xmm0,[rad]` like a normal person.

Comment: yes ! is a step from this: https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=20807 the result of external cos is ok , but I cannot sum these result of xmm0.

Comment: re: your code on the linked forum: As Agner Fog's calling-convention doc explains, *all* the XMM regs are call-clobbered.  You can't `movaps` to xmm3 for safe-keeping across another `call cos`, you have to assume `cos` destroys xmm3.  So you should reserve some stack space and store there, then `addsd xmm0, [rsp]` after the 2nd `call cos`.  Or better, find a vectorized `cos` function (https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/libmvec) that computes 2 results in parallel, and do a horizontal add of the results.  (`movhlps xmm1, xmm0` / `addsd xmm0, xmm1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it :

```
format elf64
extrn printf

section '.data' writeable align 16
rad dq 7.0
fmt db "%.30lf",0ah,0

section '.text' executable align 16
public main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    pxor xmm0,xmm0
    movsd xmm0,[rad]
    movsd xmm2,[rad]
    addsd xmm0,xmm2
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,fmt
    call printf

    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```